# How to run a method after a scene2d being rendered in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I want to make a screenshot with

```
ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);
```

I call this function in Actions.run(new Runnable{...}) in scene2d.ui, and the problem is that actions are called at very beginning of a new frame, so nothing is rendered yet.

How to call this method properly, e.g.

```
Scene.inTheEnd(run(ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);));
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Stage` has the 2 methods `act()` and `draw()`.
The `act()` method calls `act()` for all it's `Actor`s.
The `Actor`s `act()` method updates all it's `Action`s, so your screenshot is taken while the `Stage` is acting.
The `draw()` method calls `draw()` for all (visible) `Actor`s and is usually called after the `act()` method.
The screenshot should be taken after the `draw()` method. Usually `act()` and `draw()` should be called inside the `render` of your `Screen` or `ApplicationListener` and there you should also take the screenshot:

```
public void render (float delta) {
    this.stage.act(delta);
    this.stage.draw();
    Pixmap screenshot = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);
    // do something with the screenshot
}
```